# How to change the content of the UITableView with a button click?

Tags: iphone, arrays, uitableview, event-handling, uibutton

I have a UItableview with array of contents in it.There are two array ,I want to switch the array by using a button click.
My code is

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

tab.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tab.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.chapterAndVerse.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row+1];
cell.chapterAndVerse.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:17.0];
cell.chapterAndVerse.frame=CGRectMake(0, 10, 30.0, 20.0);
cell.textLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@",[delegate.allSelectedVerseMalayalam objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"testfont" size:18];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

my array is delegate.allSelectedVerseMalayalam ,I want this array to be changed with delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish in button click.When the button for english is clicked by the user it changes the tableviewcontent(my table names is tab)to delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish .How is this possible.Plese help me to figure out from this problem.
Thanks in advance.
EDIT:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
NSLog(@"%@", delegate.allSelectedVerseMalayalam);
    tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tempArray addObjectsFromArray:delegate.allSelectedVerseMalayalam];
    NSLog(@"%@", tempArray);

    [self.tab reloadData];
}
-(IBAction)_clickbtndefaultlnguageset:(id)sender
{
    [tempArray removeAllObjects];
    [tempArray addObjectsFromArray:delegate.allSelectedVerseHindi];
    [self.tab reloadData];

}
```

in tableview

```
cell.chapterAndVerse.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row+1];
cell.chapterAndVerse.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:17.0];
cell.chapterAndVerse.frame=CGRectMake(0, 10, 30.0, 20.0);
cell.textLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@",[tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

// cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"testfont" size:18];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do one thing take one extra array and allocated it 
define in your source file .h file

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray;

-(void)viewDidLoad{  
//NSLog(@"%@", your Array);  
tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
[tempArray addObjectsFromArray:yourfirstarray];  
NSLog(@"%@", tempArray);  
[self.tableview reloadData];  
}
```

after prees the button

```
-(void)pressedBtn{  
//NSLog(@"%@", your Array);
[tempArray removeAllObjects];  
[tempArray addObjectsFromArray:yoursecondArray];  
[self.tableView reloadData];  
}
```

use this temp array into table array

Comment: define array in source file. and check first your delegate array is existing or not? print the array in viewDidLoad

Comment: have you check the array is existing? have you NSLog in your code to print array in console?

Comment: what you see in the console? have you seen your array is printed? have you check your all delegate method of table view like numberOfRows....?

Comment: see means your array is not assign. it's empty. i think you have to allocate your delegate array in AppDelegate file. try to NSLog your appdelegate.allSelectedVerseMalayalam in appDelegate file so you can get idea that your main array is assign or not. reply back

Comment: if you stil face a problem then post your code with your appdelegate file code

Comment: //return YES;
     [Malayalam_BibleAppDelegate copyPlistIfNeeded];
    [self getPlistData];
 NSLog(@"%@",tabController.delegate);
 // Override point for customization after application launch
 [DbHandler createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
 
 allSelectedVerseEnglish = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease] ;
   
 allSelectedVerseMalayalam = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];
    NSLog(@"%@", allSelectedVerseMalayalam);
    allSelectedVerseHindi = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];
this is my appdeligate code in didfinishlaunching

Comment: please remove autorelease from array. and print NSlog where you assign  your array

Comment: Hi. For future reference, unless the comments is *about the post*, please take them to a chat room, they're more suited for longer discussions, and won't be flagged by our system for moderator attention.